# Can we make a curved mirror out of many small flat mirrors in telescopes?

Tags: optics, telescopes

Will it be possible to build a telescope using many small flat mirrors as a replacement for the prime curved telescope mirror?

If the answer is yes, can you please provide a formula connecting the telescope's aperture size and the maximum flat mirror size to make this work?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmented_mirror

Answer (score 3):

You can make segmented mirrors for telescopes, but each segment must be curved and not flat in order to focus the light to a single point.

Comment: Why can't flat mirrors focus light? What if each mirror would be extremely small, smaller than a millimeter. Surely there must be some limit to the perfection of the curved mirrors.

Comment: @IlyaGazman At what point would you say that a disco ball looks like a mirrored sphere?  I bet you could tell the difference by eye even if each mirror were 1 mm$^2$.  The light from a telescope needs to be focused with extreme precision - there's a reason that telescope mirrors are expensive.

Comment: @IlyaGazman Also to answer your question, flat mirrors have infinite focal length.